# Generating key bytes without KeyGenerator

Tags: encryption, jce, jca

With an environments without JCA(JCE) such as `Java ME`, would it be OK to generating key (or iv) bytes with `java.util.Random`?

```java
// MIDP
// MIDP
// MIDP

private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();


/**
 * Generates a new encryption key. This method is not intended to be used in
 * production stage.
 *
 * @return a new encryption key.
 */
protected static byte[] newKey() {

    final Random random;
    synchronized (RANDOM) {
        random = new Random(RANDOM.nextLong());
    }

    final byte[] key = new byte[256]; // AES 256
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
        key[i] = (byte) random.nextInt(256);
    }

    return key;
}
```

Is there any crypto-graphic concerns?

Is there any typos in this question including the source codes and comments? (I'm not good at in Uslish.)

Comment: For the IV I don't see any strong concern. However, for the key you really shouldn't use it. The [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) library doesn't fulfill your needs?

Comment: Actually, I couldn't find the BC class for generating secret keys without a JCA provider view.

Comment: I think `org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.symmetric.AES.KeyGen256` would do it.

Comment: `org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.symmetric.AES.KeyGen256` is not available with `lcrypto`.

Comment: You cannot use Bounce Castle as a JCA provider in JME. Use their light API.